# Error with GCM on Android emulator (with Google APIs) - register results in SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE

Tags: android-emulator, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to run the example code given in [Getting Started with GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html) on the emulator. Nothing fancier than that. Based on what I've read here, I needed to create an emulator running the Google APIs, which I have done.

One thing complicating this, perhaps, is that I'm using the new "Android Studio" tools that Google is distributing.

Anyways, I've modified the code to use my Sender ID but every time so far it's stopped at the `gcm.register(SENDER_ID)` line in the AsyncTask. It always has the same error:

```
java.io.IOException: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
 at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging.register(Unknown Source)
 at com.abc.gcmTester.MainActivity$3.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:213)
 at com.abc.gcmTester.MainActivity$3.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:205)
 at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
 at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Also, here's the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.abc.gcmTester"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />


<permission android:name="com.abc.gcmTester.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-permission android:name="com.abc.gcmTester.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.abc.gcmTester.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver
        android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
            <category android:name="com.abc.gcmTester"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
</manifest>
```

I can set up Wireshark to trace packet traffic, but I'm not sure what to look for.

I've been digging around here looking for some help but no luck... I think the emulator has the correct library but it's just not happy. Any thoughts?

Comment: This happens many times..refer to this question ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188982/how-to-fix-google-cloud-messaging-registration-error-service-not-available ...

Answer (score 0):

You have missed out the GCM Intent Receiver Service in your Manfest

```
<!--
          Application-specific subclass of GCMBaseIntentService that will
          handle received messages.
        -->
        <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
```

For GCM to work , you should have a GCMIntentService that is a subclass on GCMBaseIntentService.

Check out the GCM DemoActivity for complete information Android sdk path sdk\extras\google\gcm\samples.

Comment: If I understand your comment, your recommendation is to NOT use the GoogleClientMessenger class that Google claims has deprecated the support library and use that support library method instead? I'm OK with doing that if that's what it takes to make it work, but I'm a bit disappointed that the Google-recommended method doesn't work. Makes me wonder what other parts don't work...

Comment: (oops - GoogleClientMessenger == GoogleCloudMessenger)