# IBM Worklight - Push notification on Android

Tags: android, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying out the push notification for Android phones and tablets, and we are using the sample code given by IBM Worklight ([see blog post](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/using_worklight_to_send_push_notifications76)).

We have registered with Google GCM and have got the project id and API key; the code works fine with tablets, but when i run the same with phone isSubscribed is returning false, Can anyone please test the code which is given here and let us know what is that we are doing wrong for it to not work in multiple devices.

**LogCat from the first device - tablet running Android v3.2

Works fine.**

```
08-06 17:48:35.110: V/webview(11093):  singleCursorHandlerTouchEvent -getEditableSupport  FASLE 
08-06 17:48:40.930: V/webview(11093):  singleCursorHandlerTouchEvent -getEditableSupport  FASLE 
08-06 17:48:40.950: D/PushApplication(11093): Request [http://172.20.10.8:8080/apps/services/api/PushApplication/android/notifications]
08-06 17:48:41.470: D/PushApplication(11093): response [http://172.20.10.8:8080/apps/services/api/PushApplication/android/notifications] success: /*-secure-
08-06 17:48:41.470: D/PushApplication(11093): {"errors":[],"isSuccessful":true,"warnings":[],"info":[]}*/
08-06 17:48:41.470: V/(11093): ResourceHandle
08-06 17:48:41.520: D/dalvikvm(11093): GC_CONCURRENT freed 331K, 6% free 7957K/8455K, paused 3ms+4ms
08-06 17:48:44.710: V/(11093): ResourceHandle
08-06 17:49:02.820: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(11093): onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE
08-06 17:49:02.820: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(11093): GCM IntentService class: com.PushApplication.GCMIntentService
08-06 17:49:02.820: V/GCMBaseIntentService(11093): Acquiring wakelock
08-06 17:49:02.830: V/GCMBaseIntentService(11093): Intent service name: GCMIntentService-804999789155-4
08-06 17:49:02.830: D/WLDroidGap(11093): Received a message from the GCM server
08-06 17:49:02.830: V/GCMBaseIntentService(11093): Releasing wakelock
08-06 17:49:02.840: D/WLDroidGap(11093): Queuing message for dispatch to javascript
08-06 17:49:02.840: D/WLDroidGap(11093): Dispatching to javascript Message(alert=got a new message, badge=1, sound=sound.mp3, payload={
08-06 17:49:02.840: D/WLDroidGap(11093):    "alias": "myPush",
08-06 17:49:02.840: D/WLDroidGap(11093):    "foo": "bar"
08-06 17:49:02.840: D/WLDroidGap(11093): })
08-06 17:49:02.840: D/PushApplication(11093): WL.Client.Push received notification for alias myPush
```

**LogCat from the second device - tablet running Android v4.0.4

Subscribe button is disabled**

```
01-01 10:02:31.740: V/webview(8635):  singleCursorHandlerTouchEvent -getEditableSupport  FASLE 
01-01 10:02:31.840: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(8635): onReceive: com.google.android.gcm.intent.RETRY
01-01 10:02:31.840: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(8635): GCM IntentService class: com.PushApplication.GCMIntentService
01-01 10:02:31.840: V/GCMBaseIntentService(8635): Acquiring wakelock
01-01 10:02:31.850: V/GCMBaseIntentService(8635): Intent service name: GCMIntentService-804999789155-2
01-01 10:02:31.850: E/GCMBaseIntentService(8635): Received invalid token: 1101110000000111011000111110100011101100101100011101100111100011
```

we have removed the disabled from the sample code, which allows us to check if the tablet 2 is subscribed or not, the below logs shows clearly that the device is not subscribed.

```
01-01 10:27:13.440: V/webview(9400): NO_FAST_DRAW = false
01-01 10:27:13.640: V/webview(9400):  singleCursorHandlerTouchEvent -getEditableSupport  FASLE 
01-01 10:27:13.660: E/PushApplication(9400): Can't subscribe, notification token is not updated on the server
01-01 10:27:20.840: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(9400): onReceive: com.google.android.gcm.intent.RETRY
01-01 10:27:20.840: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(9400): GCM IntentService class: com.PushApplication.GCMIntentService
01-01 10:27:20.840: V/GCMBaseIntentService(9400): Acquiring wakelock
01-01 10:27:20.860: V/GCMBaseIntentService(9400): Intent service name: GCMIntentService-804999789155-6
01-01 10:27:20.860: V/GCMRegistrar(9400): Registering app com.PushApplication of senders 804999789155
01-01 10:27:20.870: V/GCMBaseIntentService(9400): Releasing wakelock
01-01 10:27:23.340: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(9400): onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION
01-01 10:27:23.340: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(9400): GCM IntentService class: com.PushApplication.GCMIntentService
01-01 10:27:23.340: V/GCMBaseIntentService(9400): Acquiring wakelock
01-01 10:27:23.340: V/GCMBaseIntentService(9400): Intent service name: GCMIntentService-804999789155-7
01-01 10:27:23.340: D/GCMBaseIntentService(9400): handleRegistration: registrationId = null, error = SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE, unregistered = null
01-01 10:27:23.340: D/GCMBaseIntentService(9400): Registration error: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
```

Comment: What is the phone's Android version? What does LogCat show? What is your Worklight version?

Comment: tablet is samsung galaxy tablet with android os 3.2 which is working and phone is samsung s2 and os version is 4.0.4 which is not working

Comment: So you're saying you login to the app, subscribe and then click on isSubscribe, but it returns false? What is the actual flow that you're doing to make this happen? What does LogCat show?

Comment: Hi Idan, i have shared the log cats, also issue is my second tablet is not getting subscribed for some reason, and this is the problem, but i am not able to find a fix. please help

Comment: Are you trying to login with the same username in both tablets, or different usernames?

Comment: I tried same and different,both attempts don't work.

Comment: This second device is connected to the same network as Worklight Server?

Comment: Also note that the error message is SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE. Nothing Worklight can do about that... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188982/how-to-fix-google-cloud-messaging-registration-error-service-not-available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your internet connectivity because the error you see in the log from your second device is :

```
01-01 10:27:23.340: V/GCMBaseIntentService(9400): Intent service name: GCMIntentService-804999789155-7
01-01 10:27:23.340: D/GCMBaseIntentService(9400): handleRegistration: registrationId = null, error = SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE, unregistered = null
01-01 10:27:23.340: D/GCMBaseIntentService(9400): Registration error: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
```

This means you app is not able to register with GCM service to get the token, as GCM service seems to be unavailable, hence the error SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE, may be becuase of your internet connectivity issue or GCM might have been unavailable when you tried this. So try for few more times.

Also please note that, now you are running your app on another device which means you need to do the subscription again even though you log in as same user (as on first device).So isSubscribed() is right in returning false.

Subscribe call essentially means subscribe the logged in user on this particular device to given event source. Since you have not yet subscribed for this second device (even though the same user is subscribed on first device), isSubscribed() returns false.