# Google cloud messaging, service not available

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

i'm creating an application and i'm using GCM to receive notifications, the problem is that when i call the function " gcm.register(SENDER_ID);" i'm getting "service not available".
i searched a lot and many are facing this problem,
i tried this solution:

[GCM SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE on Android 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618982/gcm-service-not-available-on-android-2-2/17721385#17721385)

but it is not working,(regId is null)
please any one can help?

Comment: Make sure you have `Google Play Service` installed on the device you are testing. Also, if you are testing on a emulator this won't work.

Comment: i'm sure that Google play service is installed and i'm testing on a device. Actually it is working fine for sometimes and some other times it is not

Comment: Look into this you will get answer from this question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188982/how-to-fix-google-cloud-messaging-registration-error-service-not-available/23486271#23486271

Answer (score 5):

The documentation says that:

> When the application receives a
>   com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION intent with the error
>   extra set as SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE, it should retry the failed
>   operation (register or unregister).

with other words, the registration failed on GCM servers and you should retry the operation again.

Make sure that you have Google Play Services installed on the device, and that you are on a stable internet connection.

Comment: yes may be i have to retry the operation, but i thought there may be a solution...