# Google Cloud Messaging Registration error: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE? same project works fine on my laptop?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have gcm project its work fine on my laptop but while i import and run it on my pc it throws Service Not Available issue;
even i try these solution but still facing issues,

1.Check you have an active internet connection
2.Check that you have Internet permission in your manifest
3.Make sure the package name is correct 
4The device time is correctly setup. Even if everything is perfect, it will fail if device clock is not set correctly.
5.google play service jar is available.
6.google play service lib is also installed.
   i am using same sdk for both pc and laptop .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue Everything is ok but the problem is in my appcompact 7 library ,i removed it and now its work fine .

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to regenrate the SHA1 key for your laptop and get a key from google console for that signature and then use that key in your application, manifest.You are using old key on your laptop and that might create problem.

Comment: i didnt use any key in manfiest . but i made project three time in my pc with diffrent names but alls are working. but it is still not working.

Comment: i am talking about sender Id that u get from Google Console

Comment: issue is because of my appcompact 7 i removed it and now my app works fine.

Comment: for more info can check [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25129611/gcm-register-service-not-available/25183437#25183437)