# Android - GCM: Failed to complete token refresh

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, access-token

I'm working with **GCM**, and I managed to receive the registration token but **when app data are deleted** - that is one of the case in which the registration token is refreshed- I'm getting this error that is driving me mad:

```
04-10 23:51:39.819 23048-26249/com.adall.teambuilding D/RegIntentService: Failed to complete token refresh
                                                                      java.io.IOException: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzc.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzc.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.zzc(Unknown Source)
                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.getToken(Unknown Source)
                                                                          at com.adall.teambuilding.gcm.RegistrationIntentService.onHandleIntent(RegistrationIntentService.java:52)
                                                                          at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                          at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

As suggested on the website I'm doing exponential attempts to retry but it's not working 
What should I do to fix the problem ? 
**Thx** anticipately

Comment: post your code and manifest please

Comment: I got the same error. But oddly enough after a second try it worked.

Answer (score 0):

A [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25129611/gcm-register-service-not-available) was raised were they resolved the issue by using `Thread.sleep`. Another answer suggests using `getApplicationContext()` when getting an instance of `GoogleCloudMessaging` (`GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(getApplicationContext())`)