# InstanceID.getToken fails on nexus devices

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

When I am trying to get `GCM` token `InstanceId` throws an `IOException`.

I have this issue only on nexus devices 4 and 5
Google play services = 8.4.0
android 5.1.1 and 6.0.1

On samsung devices I can get `GCM` token and receive push messages.

```
String token = InstanceID.getInstance(mContext)
                    .getToken(defaultSenderId, GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);

W/GCM: Missmatched messenger
W/System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: TIMEOUT
```

Comment: It can be a network issue!

Comment: But other devices work fine, only nexuses don't

Comment: Are all of them connected to the same internet network?

Comment: Yes, wi-fi -> VPN -> INTERNET

Comment: I use several Nexus emulators with GCM no issue, both Marshmallow and Lollipop, so I can confirm that they do work. 
Could this possibly be related:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24875009/gcm-error-service-not-available/26490466#26490466
Looks like maybe just a device reboot to reset the wifi

Answer (score 0):

Try invoking the `getToken()` method on another thread instead of main thread, like:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //code
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: Can you post the complete code that generates the token?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that problem is with our VPN. I don't know what's wrong, but without VPN everything works fine, thank you guys.