# Amazon-Android Registration Error(601): SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, registration, google-cloud-messaging, service-not-available

Today I tried to implement the Amazon push notification into my android app.

I followed this instruction: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-gcm.html

But at the third step when I start the "AndroidMobilePushApp" there comes no Registration ID in the LogCat there are just these lines:

```
 10-25 20:39:44.313: D/dalvikvm(601): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
10-25 20:39:45.144: I/dalvikvm(601): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-25 20:39:45.394: E/dalvikvm(601): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Is a directory
10-25 20:39:45.653: I/dalvikvm(601): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
10-25 20:39:45.713: I/dalvikvm(601): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-25 20:39:45.743: I/onResume(601): no missed messages
10-25 20:39:45.993: I/onResume(601): no missed messages
10-25 20:39:46.053: D/gralloc_goldfish(601): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
10-25 20:39:52.413: I/Registration Error(601): SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
```

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

This means the GCM service is currently unavailable and should be retried.  checkout [How to fix Google Cloud Messaging Registration error: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188982/how-to-fix-google-cloud-messaging-registration-error-service-not-available)