# GCM not working for Indefinite time showing error "SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE"?

Tags: android, performance, google-play-services

I am working in the android application and using GCM service. I face the problem that sometimes **GCM** service showing problem ("**SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE**") and its more shocking that it will work after **indefinite** time may be after 1hr or 5hr. Our project team is discussing whether we should rely on this service given by Google or not.

Comment: Use retry method at certain time intervals despite the possibility of GCM service problems as you mentioned. I advice you to use GCM if it is your only solution.

Comment: I can go with other solutions also like "pushbot" and other ... but i looking for free service thats why use GCM...

Comment: I think GCM is pretty reliable in general, many apps using GCM in play store, it also has support for iOS. So, you can use GCM to send notification to both your Android and iOS apps. It seems like its a general service error, it might be issue with your internet connection, or your firewall block some ports. Or you need to change package name in your manifest file, you might want to check out an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17191533/4195406

Comment: ok........ i check with that...

Comment: @ztan The problem is with the mobile ...... actually company block the google play store...... that why i am getting this error ... you right.. now it is working...fine