# Android - GCM error 'SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE' on Android 6.0.1

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am developing a chat application for Android. But while trying to register with GCM, I am receiving the following error:

```
04-02 16:59:29.793 29773-30031/purepush.group101.talktoday W/InstanceID/Rpc: Found 10010
04-02 16:59:29.920 29773-30031/purepush.group101.talktoday W/System.err: java.io.IOException: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
04-02 16:59:29.922 29773-30031/purepush.group101.talktoday W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzc.zzb(Unknown Source)
04-02 16:59:29.922 29773-30031/purepush.group101.talktoday W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzc.zza(Unknown Source)
04-02 16:59:29.922 29773-30031/purepush.group101.talktoday W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.zzc(Unknown Source)
04-02 16:59:29.922 29773-30031/purepush.group101.talktoday W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.getToken(Unknown Source)
04-02 16:59:29.922 29773-30031/purepush.group101.talktoday W/System.err:     at purepush.group101.talktoday.LoginActivity$GetGCMTokenTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:240)
04-02 16:59:29.923 29773-30031/purepush.group101.talktoday W/System.err:     at purepush.group101.talktoday.LoginActivity$GetGCMTokenTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:211)
04-02 16:59:29.923 29773-30031/purepush.group101.talktoday W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
04-02 16:59:29.923 29773-30031/purepush.group101.talktoday W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
04-02 16:59:29.923 29773-30031/purepush.group101.talktoday W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
04-02 16:59:29.923 29773-30031/purepush.group101.talktoday W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
04-02 16:59:29.923 29773-30031/purepush.group101.talktoday W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
04-02 16:59:29.923 29773-30031/purepush.group101.talktoday W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
04-02 16:59:29.958 29773-29773/purepush.group101.talktoday E/GcmReceiver: Failed to resolve target intent service, skipping classname enforcement
04-02 16:59:29.958 29773-29773/purepush.group101.talktoday E/GcmReceiver: Error while delivering the message: ServiceIntent not found.
```

I am obtaining GCM token using the following code:

```
InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(context);`
regToken = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId), GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
```

**MANIFEST:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="purepush.group101.talktoday">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <permission
        android:name="purepush.group101.talktoday.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="purepush.group101.talktoday.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".ChatActivity" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="purepush.group101.talktoday" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name=".utils.GCMMessageListener"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Build.Gradle (App Module)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'purepush.group101.talktoday'
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.2'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
}
```

Now the funny thing is, this error occurs only on my Nexus 5 running 6.0.1 (Build: MMB29Q). I tested this application on my colleague's Samsung Note 4 running 5.1.1 and I was able to successfully register his device with GCM. I am getting this error with multiple of our applications using GCM only my Nexus 5.

Any help on this would be appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: Did you logged in Gmail account in your nexus 6 ? Because GCM need an  email authentication to register the GCM server

Comment: It's Nexus 5 and yea, I am logged in to my Gmail account.

Comment: Can someone please guide me what to do?

Comment: please show you App gradle file

Comment: Added build.gradle file, @MounirElfassi

Comment: Please check your "Nexus 5" clock, it should be exact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it turns out that my Google Play store wasn't working properly. I could view apps and install new ones but when I entered "My apps & games", it gave me the `Check your connection and try again` error. So, I am posting this solution for anyone who might be having a similar problem since I spend 4-5 days looking for errors and trying different fixes.

Note: This is only for rooted users.

**Steps:**

1. Open your FIle Manager. I used ES File Explorer.
2. Goto "/" or the root of your phone
3. There will be folder called `etc`
4. Inside `etc`, you'll see a file name `hosts`
5. Inside the `hosts` file, you'll see 2 IP addresses. The second one will vary depending upon your location
6. Add a `#` at the start of the 2nd IP Address. `#` will change that line to a comment

I recommend making a backup of the hosts file before editing.

Credits to "Ronny927": http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2273994

Answer (score 1):

Please check your "Nexus 5" clock, it should be exact, and try to change

```
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
```

to something like: `buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"` => i'm using this version and GCM working well with Android 6

**Update:**

I'm using this Method to register my GCM

```
 public void getRegId() {

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {
                if (gcm == null) {
                    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                }
                regid = gcm.register(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId);
                msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regid;

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
                System.out.println("Error---" + ex.getMessage());
            }
            return msg;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
            System.out.println("Registerid---" + regid);
        }
    }.execute(null, null, null);
}
```

please try it and let me know.

Comment: Clock is perfect. I'll get back to you if changing buildToolsVersion works

Comment: i have updated my answer with a method i'm using now on Marshmallow device, please try it and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same situation some days ago, it is not the problem of GCM it is the problem of our internet connection. see below points for more understanding

1. you phone is connected to wifi but there is no internet from wifi, try to google in browser, if it is working perfectly then you should try some more things, like checking play services in your device and many more.
2. your phone's data pack could have been over , it means that you are connected to internet , but you won't get any kind of data from it. this error can not be identified without checking connection to your server.

You can get additional details from this link

[How to fix Google Cloud Messaging Registration error: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188982/how-to-fix-google-cloud-messaging-registration-error-service-not-available)